# process gets killed on server when closing SSH session

Tags: java, linux, ssh, centos, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to my Linux (centos 8) server by SSH. then I run my java program on server by the command

```
java -cp /.../ app
```

everything is fine and the program runs continuously, but when I close my SSH session in PuTTY, my java program gets also killed. why it happens and how to prevent it?!

Comment: This is standard Unix behavior. Look at nohup

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior. If you want to keep running your java jar file even though you close the SSH putty session , create a shell script and try to run the java application through running  the shell script.

A sample script is shown below, you can modify according to your need :

```
Name the script : app.sh
```

Sample Script Content :

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/user/    #path where your jar file is kept
java -jar app.jar
```

Go to the location of the script :

```
Give proper execute permissions to the script app.sh :
chmod 755 app.sh

Run the script as : ./app.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   nohup java -jar test.jar &
```

nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.

In short, it stands for no hang up.

Comment: ... and how exactly does this solve the question?